# How do you write the lest cell of the row you just used in python to a excel file and to tell python to ignore that row when you run it again?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, openpyxl

So I'm new in python and I have just followed a tutorial to automate filling website forms with my customer data, but I have hundreds of rows of customer data that i need to fill on 3rd party websites and I need to dobule check the data before sending to the other website, so I need to track did python alreday input that row of user data to the website.

I want to mark the last cell of the row as done or true with boolean after running all the code and the script should only read the rows with the last cell that is Nan or false the next time i run it.

Is there anyway to achieve this or is there other better ways to solve this issue?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time
import openpyxl
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx') # the excel file


driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.get('example.com') 

time.sleep(2)

for i in df.index: #read the first row that are not marked as true or done in the last cell
    entry = df.loc[i]

    Ad = driver.find_element_by_id('street_address_1')
    Ad.send_keys(entry['Address'])

    city = driver.find_element_by_id('city')
    city.send_keys(entry['City'])

    select_state = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('state'))  
    select_state.select_by_value(entry['State'])

    zip = driver.find_element_by_id('zip_code') 
    integer_zip = entry["zipcode"] 
    string_zip = str(integer_zip) 
    zip.send_keys(string_zip)

    email_address= driver.find_element_by_id('email_address')
    email_address.send_keys(entry['email'])
    
    #mark last cell of row as done or True
```

Comment: What is the point of filling the form with multiple instances of Address/City/State/zipcode/email without sending an Enter key? So how do we know when a row is processed? And do you mean you would like to restart the program if for some reason it doesn't complete and you want start with those rows that have not already been processed? A better way is to not use a spreadsheet but a database table, which can be as simple as using the built-in *sqlite* database engine, and updating new column `processed` from 0 to 1 after each row is processed.

Comment: Im new to python but i want to auto fill-in forms for my clients so i followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nz0nk2L11M0. 

But sometimes I need to put in some additional info like uploading photos and so i need to double check the submission. What I want to achieve is to mark the row as processed after sending all the keys that would fill all the input boxes so that when I run the py file again it will run the 2nd row.

I wish to use the built-in database as well, but I can't find any how to do it videos that combines pandas+selenium and for my specific use case.

Comment: To do what you want to do I reckon you should use openpyxl directly and not via Pandas. It's easy to create a header:column dictionary and you can then add a column with `True` after processing.